# How can I improve the performance of a Perl/DBI script that selects 1 million+ rows from one database server and inserts them on another?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I am using the latest versions of MySQL (workbench), Perl, and DBI.

I have two unique databases each on unique servers. I am querying table1 on DB1 on Server1, loading into an array, then with a `while` inserting said table into table2 on DB2 on Server2.

It is not a direct copy as I am actually doing a select on the table 1.

I am trying to speed up my script or if necessary change the queries.

I am using binds and have moved the prepare statements out of the loop and that has really helped. However, I still end up making 1.6 million calls to insert to table2/db2/server2, and that is using vast amounts of time (3100 seconds or about 2-3 ms per call).

There are two subs &insert2tempData which is used in the `while` loop to load my DB2 table2. It is called 1.6 million times AND query_dev_load_local_dbs which is used to query DB1 then call the second sub.

For simplicity I left this prepare in the loop, but in my code this is not in the `while` loop it is in the sub that calls this sub.

```
sub insert2tempData {
    $query4tmpData = $Locdbh_NetCool->prepare ("INSERT INTO kpincpolldata.kpitempData
        (monitoredObjectId, monitoredInstId, pollTime, tdwTime, errorCode, value)
        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    $query4tmpData->execute($row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3], $row[4],
                            $row[5]);
    warn "Problem in retrieving results", $query4tmpData->errstr(), "\n"
        if $query4tmpData->err();

} #End sun insert to tempData
```

**This is the main sub used to query the server1, DB1, and table1. It calls the `while` loop**

```
sub query_dev_load_local_dbs {
    $queryRemote = $Devdbh_NetCool->prepare("SELECT * FROM ncpolldata.pollData
                                   WHERE pollTime >= $STARTU AND pollTime < $ENDU
                                   AND monitoredObjectId = 1");

    $queryRemote->execute();

    while (@row = $queryRemote->fetchrow_array()) {

        #** Call to sub insert2tempData**
        &insert2tempData($Locdbh_NetCool);

        warn &print2log ("Problem in retrieving results"), $queryRemote->errstr(), "\n"
            if $queryRemote->err();
    } # End while

} # End sub query_dev_load_local_dbs
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Is this working code? Is your question about improving the performance?

Comment: That's a lot of rows to insert.  Depending on how table 2 is designed, it might not have _anything_ to do with the above code.  Are you doing one commit per insert or all the inserts in one transaction?  Have you consulted a DBA-type about the table design?

Comment: Giles, Yes it works fine, Yes i want to improve the performance.

Comment: Use bulk import/export. SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE and LOAD DATA INFILE ... ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's entirely possible the code you posted above *has nothing to do* with your perceived performance issue.  It might take a long time to insert that many rows on the database server you are using.  Here's what I'd look at:

1. Turn `AutoCommit` off, it's enabled.

   Committing each time you `insert` can have serious performance implications on `Server2` depending on how it's configured.  It's entirely possible that batching up the entire process into one transaction could speed things up.  But it really depends on the way the server is configured, how indexes are built, etc.

   Which brings us to:
2. A competent DBA might be able to help.

   Check with whoever it is that manages your MySQL servers and see if they can help you troubleshoot.  Who knows, they might even have DBA tools that will help solve your problem without you doing anything different in the code *or even* allow you to scrap this script altogether.

   Unless you are the DBA:
3. You might poke around the [Stack Exchange site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) for DBAs.

There might be some minor things to fix in the code you posted, but if the database is the bottleneck, it won't matter.  Find the bottleneck!

Comment: @John and to whomever edited my question for clarity THANK YOU. I do know for a fact that server 2 is not "production server" material. I ran some tests and it looks like, in addition to the demands of my script, that server 2 has very low amount of ram and the cpu is "older". I suspect this in combination with "Not fully optimized code" is my problem.  I plan to finish the optimizations and due my testing with a smaller data set. Then I will move it to production.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use [`fetchrow_arrayref()`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.622/DBI.pm#fetchrow_arrayref) instead of `fetchrow_array()` because that way it doesn't have to make copies of all the return values each time you fetch a row. That should speed things up a bit. You might also take a look at [`bind_columns`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.622/DBI.pm#bind_columns).

Then I didn't quite get what you meant with the `while` loop and the `prepare`, so I say that anyway: Move the `$query4tmpData=$Locdbh_NetCool->prepare` out of the sub and to somewhere else where it can be `prepare`d once and then reuse it in the sub. You probably have that.

---

**A few more things:**

- You should always [`use strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and `use warnings`. I don't see [`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) in your subs. Please use those pragmas. They make your life easier.
- The warning you issue when you cannot `INSERT` reads *"Problem in retrieving results"*. That might confuse you if it occurs.

Comment: Good advice all.  Hopefully the OP will take this in consideration even it doesn't directly speed up processing.

Comment: @John - Thank you. Yes I do use strict and warning (I just didn't include that code) Also yes in my production code I do have prepare statements out of any loops.

Comment: @John Simb - Giles I will test out the array reference I bet that will save me a bunch of time. I will also study Bind Col. I was just reviewing my MySql reference and these 2 things tuck out as options.

Comment: Thank you all for your great responses. I will report back my success